# chart.js : empty doughnut after getting data from database

Tags: javascript, angular, spring-boot, chart.js

Putting data from a database into an array in chart.js is  not working and gives an empty doughnut:

i'm using angular / spring boot for back end

```
constructor(private statistiqueService:StatistiqueService) { 
    this.statistiqueService.getStateClient().subscribe(
      resp=>{
        for(var i=0;i<resp.length;i++){
          this.dataStatus[i]=resp[i][1];
          this.labelStatus[i]=resp[i][0];
        }

      }
    );
  }

  statusClient(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'doughnut',
      data: {
        datasets: [{
            data: this.dataStatus,
            backgroundColor: [
              'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.8)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.8)'
          ]
        }],    
        labels:this.labelStatus
    }
  });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
          console.log("Data");
          console.log(this.dataStatus);
          console.log("Label");
          console.log(this.labelStatus);
    this.statusClient();
  }
```

My data after log is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTx7X.png)

Comment: Can you add a Stackblitz with a simplre preproduction. This way it is easier to help